# unable to fetch license using Enterprise License Manager API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am retrieving the user license associated to a domain using `https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/reference/rest/v1/licenseAssignments/listForProductAndSku?authuser=2#http-request`

It was working fine till 4 Aug 2022 and suddenly stop working. i am receiving below error message each time.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Unauthorized operation for the given domain.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unauthorized operation for the given domain.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same error response if you try using the API explorer in that page you shared?

Comment: Yes, Same error in API explorer as well, I have tried with two domains. Both user are super admin

Comment: I found this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/157926132), and they mentioned a workaround to use the domain name as the customerId parameter. Could you test if that works? Do you get the same issue in the ["Try this API"?](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/reference/rest/v1/licenseAssignments/listForProductAndSku?apix=true) If you do, you can create an [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/support#bugs) or contact Google Support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17390145/giselle-valladares, It is a very old issue and i am passing customerId. It was working till 4 Aug 2022.

Comment: In that case, and as you mentioned that it happens in the API explorer, I think it will be best to create a new issue tracker or contact Google Support, so they can help you with it. Make sure to mention that it happens in the API explorer.

Comment: I agree with Giselle, you should reach Google Workspace support team or create a new ticket by going to this page https://support.cloud.google.com/portal/cases .

Answer (score 1):

You should go to https://admin.google.com and add the user account or service account you're using on the API call to a Role with permission to Read Licenses.

- On the Google Admin Console go to **Account/Admin Roles**
- Add a **new role** with the permissions you need **or select "Super User" role**.
- Click on the **Admins Assigned** section.
- Click button to **add a user or service account**.

You should wait some minutes to get it applied.

On my case I cannot add services accounts to superuser role, so I needed to create a new one with just the permissions I need.